# How to navigate from Salesforce1 app to Other Native Apps in iOS 13 Using Javascript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

We are currently working on one of Visualforce page which is running in Salesforce1 application. I need to navigate on one of iOS native application from this page. 
Earlier I was using - `window.top.location = '<appurl>';` 
This command is working as expected in iOS 12 and it's earlier versions. When I run same page on one of my iOS device having iOS 13.0 version, it's not navigating me to iOS native app.

I have implemented following solutions, in order to resolve this navigation issue -

```
1. window.location = '<appurl>';
2. document.location = '<appurl>';
3. window.location.href = '<appurl>';
4. location.replace("<appurl>");
5. window.top.location = '<appurl>';
6. location.href = '<appurl>';
7. window.location.assign("<appurl>");
```

Here following is my code snippet -

```
var versionNumberiOS = parseFloat(getiOSversion());

if(versionNumberiOS != null && versionNumberiOS < 13.0) {
   window.top.location = '<url>'; //this works for ios  < 13
} else {
   window.location = '<url>'; //Here I need to implement solution
}

function getiOSversion() {

   if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {

     var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
     return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
   }
}
```

Please help me out to resolve navigation issue on iOS 13.0 version by using javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.location.href = "other_page.html";
},500);
```